# Maven won't create runnable jars

Tags: java, maven, jsoup, manifest, program-entry-point

My pom.xml looks like this

```
...
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>application.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  ...
```

but although I specified the main class, on `clean package install` maven only creates jars that aren't runnable.

How can I fix that? The manifest then looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: Matthias
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_121
```

Comment: Off topic: no need to call both `package` and `install`; they're both part of the build-lifecycle. The result is that Maven first executes from `validate` to `package`, followed by `validate` to `install`.  I'd suggest: just run `mvn verify` instead (avoid `install`, but that is a different topic) and your build will almost be twice as fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of maven compiler plugin, you should configure the maven jar plugin to create an executable jar :

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>              
      <archive>
        <manifest>          
            <mainClass>application.Main</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

To declare the source/target java version you could use :

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

instead of declaring the compiler plugin. 
This is less verbose and it produces exactly the same result.

Besides, if you want to include dependency jars of your application inside your executable jar, you should favor the maven assembly plugin over the maven jar plugin :

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>application.Main</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: I copied the code, replaced the compiler plugin with the jar plugin and added the two properties lines. It builds, but the "Main-Class: application.Main" is still not present. Thanks anyways for the assembly plugin!

Comment: You are welcome :) Have you run the `mvn clean package` command and can you check the `plugins` tag is a direct child of the `build` tag in the pom.xml ?

Comment: Well I'm using this pom: http://pastebin.com/PEYMjT4R
And I execute `clean package install`

Comment: `mvn clean package install` makes no sense as `install` is a phase located after `package` and by default all previous tasks of the lifecycle are executed before the requested phase. So `mvn clean install` is enough. In your pom.xml, you mix two ways of doing. Either use maven-jar-plugin or use maven-assembly-plugin, not both. Besides, in the maven-assembly-plugin, you don't refer the mainClass as I shown in my answer. With these changes, it should be ok :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, now it works perfectly.